# Please help me to solve a task in combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

Please help me to solve this task:

```
A)How many different 4 digit numbers is possible ti create from this digits: 1,2,4,5,7,8,9?
B)How many of them will be odd and even?
```

The answers is A)840 B)360,480

I got stuck with **B** I can;t understand how they got 360 and 480.

Comment: They are $4$ even digits and $5$ odd digits, so the total must be divided in $4/9$ of even numbers and $5/9$ of odd numbers.

Comment: Can the digits be used more than once? For b) use the fact that a number is odd if it ends with an odd digit.

Comment: @Muralidharan no only once

Comment: @Masacroso, it's 4 odd (1,5,7,9) and 3 even (2,4,8)

Comment: Yes, whatever. Are you sure that each digit can only be used once? In any case let the even digits and construct all possible number with 3 digits with the other digits, after add the odd digits at the end. The same for the odd ones.

Comment: @Masacroso using each digit only once does not change the proportion odd and even in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) The first digit can be any one of 7, the second is any one of remaining 6 etc. Thus the number of 4 digit numbers is $7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 840$. For b) the last digit has 4 choices (1,5,7,9). The other three digits can be filled in $6 \times 5 \times 4$. Hence the number of odd numbers is 480. Even numbers are remaining $840 - 480 = 360$.

Comment: Can u expalin please how you got 480?

Comment: It is $6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 4$; there are 4 choices for last digit and $6 \times 5 \times 4$ choices for the other 3 when the number is odd. Hence we have $6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 4 = 480$